# Error: Could not find or load main class org.ros.RosRun

Tags: ros, client-rosjava, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I started the tutorial about  [rosjava services](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/UsingServices) recently. I've been following all the steps until I got to the final one where I need to execute rosrun in order to run the server and the client.

The problem I've found is that rosrun can't find org.ros.RosRun. I've sourced rosjava environment as well as executing roscore before attempting to run the server and the client. However, it is possible to execute the server and the client if you do it outside rosrun e.g.  typing in the terminal

`./build/install/client_server/bin/client_server org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_services.Client`

Also, I've taken a look at previous topics and I've found a similar behaviour among the questions, but I didn't find a solution suitable for my problem. Some examples can be found [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/101691/cant-execute-rosjava-nodes-rosrun-not-found-exception/) and [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/34092/problem-running-rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/)

I use Ubuntu 16.04 as well as ROS Kinetic, installing rosjava from sources. I've also tried installing rosjava from apt packages but I've the same results.

Is it a common problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317560/error:-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org.ros.rosrun/) by [anonymous40337](https://answers.ros.org/users/40337/anonymous40337/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've a quick update:

The problem was related with the opcion chosen: if you choose option 2 [as indicated in the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/UsingServices) you execute a package that is not inside the bin folder. You need to type the option that contains the bin folder.

I was able to find the solution because of  [the pubsub tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28Java%29). There indicates that you need to select the opcion that contains the bin folder.

Thank you again!

---

Originally posted by [anonymous40337](https://answers.ros.org/users/40337/anonymous40337/) with karma: 16 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2019-03-06**:
Interesting observation; yes, the correct one is in the bin folder.